# Why does strcpy trigger an error?

Tags: c

The program works fine if the string is not copied using `strcpy`, but I would like to know the reason why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{

    int mat;
    char test1[20]={"Hex"} ;
    char test2[20]={"agonal"} ;

    strcpy(test1,"Diagonal"); // the print outputs the concatenated test if strcpy is commented out

    //printf("a=%c\nb=%c\n",test1[0],test1[1]);

    printf("Concatenated test=%s", strcat(test1, test2));

    return 0;
}


ERROR MESSAGE

*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./prog terminated
      ======= Backtrace: =========
      /lib/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x48)[0xb75b6ae8]
      /lib/libc.so.6[0xb75b4b30]
      /lib/libc.so.6[0xb75b3dcd]
     ./prog(__gxx_personality_v0+0x14d)[0x804858d]
     ./prog(__gxx_personality_v0+0x31)[0x8048471]
      ======= Memory map: ========
```

Comment: "Diagonal" + "agonal" is greater than 10

Comment: This is why preferring functions like `strncat` and `strncpy` which specify a max size is a good idea.

Comment: It appears, that the error was **corrected in the question** above (array sizes changed from 10 to 20). This means that all the answers below now don't appear to make any sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `strcat` call is the one failing. You don't have enough space in `test1` to store the concatenation of `"Diagonal"` and `"agonal"`.

If you make `test1` big enough, it should work:

```
char test1[40]={"Hex"} ;
```

Comment: Candy from baby job!  Just the title gave away a string space allocation problem. Still, you were first, so I'll add another point..

Answer (score 2):

The `strcat` call overflows the destination buffer.

P.S. You just increased `test1` size to 20, now it should work.

Comment: I felt stupid ,just after reading Pablos answer and thus the edit :)

Comment: @user1630275: Now nobody else would understand your question

Comment: Your answer says it all :) I cant upvote until I have atleast 15 rep !

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this strcpy will lead you to concatenating *Hex* with *Diagonal* and trying to store it inside 10 elements array. 
And length of *HexDiagonal* is...

Answer (score 0):

Remember one more thing .... When strcpy is used ... then it copy the *sourse* to the *destination* with NULL CHARACTER ... That's why destination should have enough memory ...